# Cannot access the filesystems using LiveCD (LVM2,EXT2)

Tags: mount, lvm

I have to restore the `/etc/passwd` file I accidentally renamed in my Ubuntu Server, so I booted the machine using a LiveCD.

Problem is, the system filesystem does not appear in Nautilus, under 'Devices'. 
Am I missing anything?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000956dc

Device Boot         Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   8e  Linux LVM


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="aad69790-198d-45bc-9ccd-e4cba7456914" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="wbIDX7-RILL-VtFT-gX15-N1GJ-Yyfg-V8Oe5m" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660"

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
overlayfs / overlayfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Comment: Edit your question to show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and of `mount` (from the live CD system).

Comment: @quntbert Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime it happens I don't know exactly why.. But you can mount it manually and I guess after mounting it will show. If you prefer to find a way to mount your disk then follow these steps.

- Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute this.

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  it will show something:

  ```
  /dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows" UUID="FA50DCB150DC763B" TYPE="ntfs" 
  /dev/sda5: LABEL="40GBTWO" UUID="00A0CE7EA0CE7A24" TYPE="ntfs" 
  /dev/sda6: UUID="7550252c-3da7-4cd9-8da3-71e9ba38e74a" TYPE="ext4" 
  /dev/sda7: UUID="088fd084-a011-4896-aa93-c0caaad60620" TYPE="swap" 
  /dev/sdb1: LABEL="SaurK" UUID="1B7B3C0764A21F1F" TYPE="ntfs"
  ```

  i,e all partitions of your hard-drive including the external one, whether it is mounted or not.
- Now you can mount any of the partition by executing this command:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda1
  ```

  if you want to mount `/dev/sda1` replace `/sda1` to the partition you want to mount.
- Although it's now needed but I tell you to unmount you can execute:

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sda1
  ```

  use the same logic as described in previous command.

**Edit**

As you can see your `/dev/sda1` as well as `/dev/sda5` entry is not in `/etc/fstab`. You can manually mount your partitions by following these steps.

- First make a mount-point where you want to mount the partitions. Generally all the partitions mounted in `/media`. You've to create directory there in order to mount the partitions. Execute following in terminal to make two directory there:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/part1 /media/part2
  ```
- Now you have to make changes in `/etc/fstab` in order to mount you `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5` partitions. Execute following commands to do so:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```

  go to the last line and add these lines:

  ```
  UUID=aad69790-198d-45bc-9ccd-e4cba7456914 /media/part1    ext2    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  UUID=wbIDX7-RILL-VtFT-gX15-N1GJ-Yyfg-V8Oe5m /media/part2   LVM2_member    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  ```

  <sub>**A little explanation:** UUID="contains the ID of your hard disk partitions, 1st is of `/dev/sda1` and 2nd is of `/dev/sda5` partitions. `sudo blkid` command is very useful to get the partitions information like **UUID**, **File-system type**, **partition entry** etc.. So any one can use it to get their information. `/media/part1` is the mount entry of 1st partition and `/media/part2` is for 2nd. Remember why I created two directories above. `ext2` is the file system type of your 1st partition: `/dev/sda1`. It may be something else also like: `ext3`, `ext4`, `ntfs`, `fat` etc, you can get the info from `sudo blkid` command as I mentioned above. others will be same for all types of file-system, it tells that if any error occurs then `remount the file system in read-only mode` [this link](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/200709/page07.html) is a great tutorial.</sub>

  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit. Press <kbd>y</kbd> when prompt to save.
- `LVM2_member` is quite a different file system, if adding it's info to `/etc/fstab` doesn't help then you can mount it by:

  ```
  sudo modprobe dm-mod; sudo vgchange -ay
  ```

  if needed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lvm2
  ```
- You can mount `/dev/sda1` by executing:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda1
  ```

Hope it will help you to recover from your problem.

Comment: When I try to mount it, I receive the message `can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Comment: Ok got it.. You've to manually edit `/etc/fstab` and do the changes to mount the drive. Let me edit my answer. and I also want to post you the output of this command: `sudo blkid`. It would be better if you provide the output of this command also: `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Added the output to my response.

Comment: Thanks. I still had a problem of not being able to mount `LVM2_member`. These lines helped me out: `modprobe dm-mod`; `vgchange -ay`

Comment: Actually `LVM2_member` is quite a different file system and mounting it is different. Sorry I didn't know and thought that it would be mounted like the same way. But never mind you can find the way to mount in [this link](http://www.linux-sxs.org/storage/fedora2ubuntu.html) or [this](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Mounting_a_Linux_LVM_volume.html) But I think that you don't need that to solve your problem, because that is not needed right? Mounting the first partition would solve your issue.. Right..?

Comment: Actually I had to mount `sda5` to access my filesystem. I managed to do it with those lines I mentioned.

Comment: @ftkg: It would be good if you edit my answer and mention how did you manage to `mount` LVM2_member file system. Not only it will make the answer complete, it will help others to solve their problems though. :)

Comment: @ftkg: Since you didn't show any interest to edit the post, I've mentioned the way to mount `LVM2_member` file-system, as you mentioned in the 4th comment of this post. Just want from you to review it once..!