# Installing Ubuntu along with fedora and win 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, window, fedora

I have system in my lab with Fedora and windows 7 installed in it.

While booting up, the system first shows up fedora and then inside fedora, i can select whether to load windows 7.

I tried windows installer but it is giving an error at the end of installation.

I was wondering if its possible to install ubuntu without removing fedora and windows.

Is it possible to "shrink volume" from windows and install ubuntu in the partition ? Will it affect the fedora. I dont want fedora to be removed as it may be used by others.

Comment: You can use Windows 7 also to shrink/enlarge the existing partition to a new one.. When you boot Ubuntu you've install it one the partition that you created by Windows 7. So installing Ubuntu to a new partition will not harm any existing operating system.

Comment: @Saurav Kumar I created a partition using Shrink Volume feature in Windows and installed ubuntu in it. When the system boots up, it only shows fedora and Windows but not ubuntu...How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) once. All information is given at the site.

Comment: after using Boot-repair , there is only ubuntu and win 7. Fedora is missing. Fedora does not show up while boot up. Moreover, the space in which Fedora was installed is not added into other operating system. So Fedora is still there but not seen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install **Fedora** with its default file system LVM?

In Ubuntu you need to add the `lvm` drivers then mount the Fedora partitions then you've to update your grub in order to get **Fedora** on the list.

So follow these steps:

- Install **LVM** drivers:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install lvm2
  ```
- Mount the **Fedora** partition:

  You can use these link for more help:

  - [Cannot access the filesystems using LiveCD (LVM2,EXT2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361310/cannot-access-the-filesystems-using-livecd-lvm2-ext2)
  - [Fedora to Ubuntu](http://www.linux-sxs.org/storage/fedora2ubuntu.html)
  - [Mounting a Linux LVM Volume](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Mounting_a_Linux_LVM_volume.html)
- Then update your **grub**

  ```
   sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your system.

After restart you should **Fedora** option on the **grub** menu.